# How do I alter vue component programmaticaly?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

In my Vue component, I have several similar bits of code.

In template:

```
<modal v-model="contractChangeFlag">
...
</modal>
<modal v-model="contractCloseFlag">
...
</modal>
```

In data:

```
    chagedContract: null,
    closedContract: null,
```

In computed:

```
   contractChangeFlag: {
      get: function() { return this.changedContract !== null; },
      set: function(v) { if ( !v) { this.changedContract = null; },
   },
   // the same code for contractCloseFlag
```

And appropriate calls in methods.

Can I make a factory to fill both data, computed and methods with templated code? Copypasting is a very bad practice.

Comment: You could use an array of values instead so you can create a `v-for` loop.

Comment: How do I create computeds using v-for?

Comment: A computed value can also be an array. In `v-model` you then use `yourComputedArray[i]` as the model. I don't know exactly how the `get`/`set` handlers would work with that, that's why I haven't written an answer... maybe in computed just: `combinedContractStates() { return [this.changedContract, this.closedContract]; }`.. this might even preserve your `get/set` methods and keeps being reactive. You then write a `v-for` loop over `combinedContractStates` and as `v-model` write `combinedContractStates[i]`.